# `line-number-mode`, but per-buffer (using `smart-mode-line` package)

Tags: mode-line, line-numbers, smart-mode-line

Is it possible to have the line number where the cursor is shown in the mode-line (or line and column numbers appearing in the buffer) only for certain buffers, while it is disabled for other buffers.

I know that I can toggle it globally with `M-x line-number-mode`, but it interactive buffers (shells) or in buffers where I write text, I don't like it.

Please note that I am using the `smart-mode-line` package.

Answer (score 3):

Line number mode is implemented as a global-minor-mode. I don't know an easy way to make it a 'normal' minor-mode (although there probably is). However, you can easily hide the line-number indicator locally by configuring the `mode-line-position-line-format`. For shells, you can achieve it e.g. as follows

```lisp
(defun hide-line-number-hook-fn ()
  (setq-local mode-line-position-line-format ""))

(add-hook 'comint-mode-hook #'hide-line-number-hook-fn)
```

For other buffers, you can use similar methods (e.g. using the org-mode and/or text-mode hooks).

Comment: That does not work for me, because I am using `smart-mode-line` package.  I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You'd need to check how/where `smart-mode-line` gets the text `%l` into `mode-line-format` then.  Or try the same answer but with `(setq-local line-number-mode nil)` instead of `(setq-local mode-line-position-line-format "")`.

Comment: Note: That last suggestion is not a generic way to "make a global minor mode buffer-local" (you would always have to read and understand *specifically* how each global mode works to figure out whether and how you could achieve that); but for this *particular* mode the variable `line-number-mode` simply controls whether or not the `%l` in the mode line format will be processed, so we *can* just set the buffer-local value of that.  (And likewise for `column-number-mode`.)

Comment: dalanicolai: I wouldn't even mention anonymous functions (here or in any other such answer). It's too easy for people to unwittingly add multiple conflicting lambdas on a hook, not understand why things aren't working, and create more confusion for themselves.

Comment: @phils Good point. I have updated the answer. Although I slightly prefer your solution of setting `line-number-mode` to nil, that solution also makes the variable nil while the mode is still 'active' (quite irrelevant, of course). Anyway, I kept the solution as is because of that, and because your suggestion is easy to find in the comments anyway. Thanks for the advice for improving the answer.